# Android app tutorial content.xml and activity.xml files have different code to tutorial

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm working through the android tutorial at
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

I've created the project as stated in the tutorial however the code that it says is supposed to be in my activity.xml file is instead in my content.xml file its as if they have swapped?

Code in activity xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_my" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Code in content xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="Hello World!" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The tutorial is telling me to change the relative layout block to linear layout (which it says should be in the activity xml, but for me its in content xml)

So when I replace the code in activity xml with what the tutorial has it gives me errors because I removed the code that was there previously.

OR

if I edit the code in content xml and run the app I can't see the changes because activity is not updated, and I cant move the linear layout code to activity xml because it gives me "multiple root tags" error.

Can someone show me a solution that will allow me to continue with the tutorial, because if I edit the java code or something like that I get problems with later stages in the tutorial.

Thanks

Comment: I have added a new answer to this... One that makes more sense to a beginner trying to make their first app on android

Comment: thanks for posting both scripts ... my `res/layout/` did not have a  `content_my.xml` at all ... so I copied your code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working on the activity.xml try editing the content.xml to reflect the LinearLayout change (do add the orientation value as shown).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="Hello World!" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Do also go through on the Android [Getting Started](http://developers.android.com) Resources. They will come in handy

Comment: Yes, but when I start adding buttons and things it stops being reflected in the activity xml?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to keep in mind that these .xml files represent the layout part, the UI.
To put it simply, a 'screen' in Android is composed of 2 files : the layout (the .xml file), and its associated .java file.
Here, we can see that your "content" is **included** in your "activity".
It's quite the same thing as putting directly the content of "content.xml" into "activity.xml".
What is in the "OnCreate()" method of you MyActivity.java ?

Have you tried replacing the "include" in "activity.xml" by the actual content of "content.xml", not forgetting to remove "root specific" values (xmlns:android, xmlns:tools, xmlns:app and tools:context)?

As fernaMuruthi said, try following the Android Getting Started Resources. Also, try not to use the graphic designer : it sometimes generate crappy code. instead, Type you UI pseudo-xml directly.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. Never really worked with XML, and my Java is rusty. I ended up searching online a bunch and this is what I found out.

- The .xml files are used to determine your layouts for your activity. They can be used in conjunction with one another or separately. This means using content.xml and main_activity.xml don't really matter. However because the tutorial is not very clear about this, it makes it hard for newcomers to figure out a work around.
- The solution is to understand what the MainActivity.java file is doing with your .xml files. Mike James at i-programmer explains this fairly well...(http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/android/5914-android-adventures-activity-and-ui.html)
- There is a method called onCreate() that controls which layout is being used by MainActivity.java. Here you will see the auto generated function setContentView() this is the main issue with determining what is being displayed in the app.
- There is also a bunch of other generated code that is used to get more data from main_activity.xml. If you look at the code you will see what needs to be removed.

Hope this helps. Please up vote if it did :)

Answer (score 0):

So, if you follow the tutorial to a tee, i.e. make your **activity_my.xml** file the exact same as what they are expecting, then you will see the edit text view and the button view as depicted.

It seems that quite a bit has been added to the blank activity template since the creation of this tutorial, making the tutorial quite obscure.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around for a while and trying multiple solutions I finally realized that the toolbar created in activity_my.xml was obscuring the text/button created in content_my.xml.

My solution was to just pad the linear layout.

```
android:paddingTop="55dp"
```

But then again I'm on day #2 in the Android/Java world...